# C++ Pointers & Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, opencv

Below is some code from a C++ procedure.  The original can be found here;
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp

My perspective is that I am a C# rather than C++ programmer so this code is a bit of a mystery to me even though I ran it through a code converter and it came out unchanged.

My questions are: a). How does 'coefs' become an array, and b). how does 'c' get populated?

To give a bit more information: 'coefs' does not seem to start out as an array and 'c' somehow seems to magically get at least 8 items

```
    // fields in class called MAT:
    // a distance between successive rows in bytes; includes the gap if any 
    size_t step;
    // pointer to the data
    uchar* data;

    // where ptr comes from:
    template<typename _Tp> _Tp* ptr(int y=0);
    template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp* Mat::ptr(int y)
    {
        CV_DbgAssert( (unsigned)y < (unsigned)rows );
        return (_Tp*)(data + step*y);
    }    
    .....

    // original question code:
    static const int componentsCount = 5;
    Mat model;
    float* coefs;
    float* mean;
    float* cov;

    coefs = model.ptr<float>(0);
    mean = coefs + componentsCount;
    cov = mean + 3*componentsCount;

    for( int ci = 0; ci < componentsCount; ci++ )
        if( coefs[ci] > 0 )
            calcInverseCovAndDeterm( ci );

    void GMM::calcInverseCovAndDeterm( int ci )
    {
        if( coefs[ci] > 0 )
        {
            float *c = cov + 9*ci;
            float dtrm =
                covDeterms[ci] = c[0]*(c[4]*c[8]-c[5]*c[7]) - c[1]*(c[3]*c[8]-c[5]*c[6]) + c[2]*(c[3]*c[7]-c[4]*c[6]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare an array like this:

```
int my_ints[10];
```

`my_ints` *is* an array.  But in C++ `my_ints` can also be evaluated as a pointer to the first item in the array.  So code like this:

```
int* the_first_int = my_ints;
```

...is legal and valid, not to mention very common.  You can also use `the_first_int` as if it were also an array, like this:

```
int the_third_int = the_first_int[2];
```

...which makes it practically seamless to go between C-style arrays and pointers and back again.

In your code you declare a pointer to a `float`:

```
float* coefs;
```

(by the way, this should be initialized to NULLL, but that's another story), and then you set it to some value:

```
coefs = model.ptr<float>(0);
```

I don't know what `model.ptr<float>(0)` does, but it probably either allocates an array and returns a pointer to that, or returns a pointer to an array that was already set up.

Now because the `coefs` is a pointer to `float`, you can use it like it were an array, which you do in the loop:

```
for( int ci = 0; ci < componentsCount; ci++ )
    if( coefs[ci] > 0 )
```

That's why this works.

Answer (score 2):

> How does `coefs` become an array

In C and C++, `p[i]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(p + i)`. Of course, this construct is only meaningful if `p` happens to point to an element of an array and `p + i` does not march off the bounds of that array. Otherwise, you get [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105120/).

> Kos wrote: please don't just say "undefined behaviour" every time something's wrong unless you can back it up with a standard

Okay, since you were asking for it:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
>   of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is
>   large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of
>   the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression. In other words, if
>   the expression `P` points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P)`)
>   and `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i - n-th elements of the array
>   object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression `P` points to the last element of an array object,
>   the expression `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression `Q` points
>   one past the last element of an array object, the expression `(Q)-1` points to the last element of the array
>   object. **If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
>   the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Untrue... OK, technically true, but unclear :), as `p` may point to any element of an array, actually. Also, please don't just say "undefined behaviour" every time something's wrong unless you can back it up with a standard - there's still "unspecified" and "implementation-defined", and the latter basically means that there are circumstances (specific machine, architecture, compiler...) where such code would be valid.

Comment: @Kos:  I get your rant, and don't disagree with it, but this is in fact undefined behavior.

Comment: @Fred:  Saying "is p happens to point to the first element in the array, [else it is UB]"  Isn't quite right.  The correct thing to say is "if *(p+1) doesn't point to an element in the array, you get ub" is correct.  If you're going to invoke the UB gods, you should probably be correct and precise.

Comment: Are you saying that - assuming I have a POD struct of 3 32-bit floats on a 32-bit machine with GCC - if I try to reference the second float by pointer to the first increased by 1, I can expect demons flying from my nose, or - well - anything worse than people blaming me for bad style? While I can't confirm, I believe the behaviour is predictable in such case; and this is what I understand by "implementation-defined" (analogously to situation with unions, reinterpret_casts, etc). Please correct me with some source if i'm wrong here.

Comment: @Kos: Yes, I'm saying exactly that. Using pointer arithmetic to access struct members is undefined behavior, because **a struct is not an array**. The standard quote leaves no doubt: "If [...] **point to elements of the same array** [...] otherwise [...] undefined"

Comment: I'm equally surprised and convinced - I expected this situation to be treated similarly to a reinterpret_cast, which has its mapping *implementation-defined*. However, the explanation makes sense. But it's curious that it's the same in C, where there are no pointer-to-members (and this implies that you also cannot emulate them with operator `offsetof`). Also, great to know that one-past-last is still allowed :). Fred, thanks for the help, +1 obviously.

Comment: @Kos: Things can be defined by the implementation without being implementation-defined. There are many things that the C++ standard leaves as UB (which means that it is *not* implementation-defined), but there is no rule stopping the specific implementation from defining how it will behave on that specific implementation (so it will be predictable, but the C++ standard doesn't *require* it to be so, and therefore it is still UB). Things are only implementation-defined in C++ parlance if the standard says that it is defined by the implementation. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ pointers and arrays are equivalent. You can treat them as pointer or array ,tht up to you. A pointer to single variable can be considered an array of 1 element.

Comment: No, pointers and arrays **are not equivalent**. An array behaves a lot like a pointer in certain circumstances (array to pointer decay), but it **is not** a pointer. For example, `sizeof(some_array)` yields the size of the entire array, whereas `sizeof(some_pointer)` yields the size of a pointer.

Comment: `float*` and `float[1]` are distinct types that store different things.

Comment: @FredOverflow: They are equivalent ,they are not the same. int and short are equivalent ,but not the same.

Comment: How on earth are `int` and `short` equivalent?

Comment: *"An array object is **implicitly convertible** to a pointer to the array's inner type"*, in C++ terms. I cannot remember C++ having a notion of *"equivalent"*.

Comment: float x[1] = {1.0};
float *y = x;
func( x );
func( y );

void Func( float* z ) { *z = 0.0; }

Comment: @Edwin:  Standard says that sizeof(int) >= sizeof(short) >= sizeof(char).  You could concevably assign a value to an int that won't fit in a short.  They are not the same, nor are the equivilant.

Comment: Obviously you all don't realize that equivalent does not mean 'the same'

Comment: @Edwin: It does according to http://mw1.meriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivalent.  Moreover, there's no such concept as "equivilant" in the Standard.

Comment: @Edwin:  The complaint is simply that "equivilant" is imprecise, not necesarrily wrong.  If you were to replace "equivilant" with "implicitly convertible" the argument would evaporate.

Comment: @John Dibling: 1.meriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivalent (3) corresponding or virtually identical especially in effect or function

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your code that `model` is the data structure that actually contains an array.

```
coefs = model.ptr<float>(0);
```

Here, `coefs` doesn't "become" an array, but it points to the existing array in `model`, after which it can be used just like a real array. The same happens with the other variables `mean`, `cov` and `c` -- they are all assigned a pointer to a specific location within the array. For example:

```
mean = coefs + componentsCount;
```

makes `mean` point to the 6th (since `componentsCount = 5`) element of the `coefs` "array". After this, `mean` can be viewed as an array that begins from the 6th element of `model`.

Answer (score 0):

`float *c = cov + 9*ci;`

c is a pointer to wherever cov points to plus 9 times the size of a float (4 bytes assuming standard IEEE-754 `float`).  This is pointer arithmetic.

I'm unsure what coefs points to, but I assume it gets assigned somewhere in the `model.ptr<float>(0);` statement.  Otherwise, it's an invalid pointer (probably NULL).

In C and C++, there exists a breakdown of the distinction between pointers and arrays. Consider the following code:

```
int A[5];
int y = *A;  // The first occurrence of A is also the dereferenced value of *A
int z = A[0]; // The first occurrence of A
int *w = A;  // pointer to the beginning of A
if (*w == y) {} // TRUE, dereferenced int value == int value
if (w == A) {} // TRUE, address == address
```

Comment: if c is a pointer to wherever cov points to plus 9 times the size of a float (or did you mean int?), how would I write code that wanted to multiply the actual value of ci by 9 rather than its byte size?